# JPA hibernate insert row cause ConstraintViolationException

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

i have simple entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NH_ENTITIES")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Entita {
  /**
   * Primary key.
   */
  @Id
  @Column(name = "PK", nullable = false, length = NHConstants.DB_STANDARD_LENGTH)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "nh_entities_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "nh_entities_gen", sequenceName = "NH_ENTITIES_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
  private int pk;

  /**
   * Entity name.
   */
  @NotEmpty(message = "Entita je povinná")
  @Size(max = NHConstants.DB_MAX_LENGTH, message = "Maximální počet znaků: " + NHConstants.DB_MAX_LENGTH)
  @Column(name = "ENTITY", unique = true, nullable = false, length = NHConstants.DB_MAX_LENGTH)
  private String entity = "";

  /**
   * For Hibernate only.
   */
  public Entita() {
  }
}
```

and my service method:

```
  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public void saveEntity(Entita entity) {
    log.debug("Start transaction saveEntity");
    this.entityRepo.save(entity);
    log.debug("Transaction saveEntity finished");
  }
```

when i **manually** insert row/rows to this entity by some sql client and afterthat execute saveEntity programatically im getting the error
*could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [C##NH.SYS_C0013920]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement*

This error im getting just once....it depends how many rows i inserted before manually....

Is there another way how to handle this issue except execute findlast before save?

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Which database you use?

Comment: im using Oracle 12c

Comment: The problem here is you are using sequence  for primary key and its start  value is assigned to 1

Comment: so should i handle the primary key programatically without sequence generator? cant it be done this way with sequence generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. i inserted exactly the numbers sequencially in DB
It is neccessary to use the sequence for this purpose.